# How to fix "Server-Side Request Forgery" issue in spring restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, fortify

Getting "Server-Side Request Forgery" issue in Fortify report while using spring restTemplate.

I am making a call using restTemplate to some other REST service and passing this url from my controller class.
The url is hardcoded in my controller and not user-controlled data.

```
HttpEntity<R> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
parameterizedTypeReference);
```

Not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have your peers review your code and if they agree then flag the warning as a false positive. Static scanners can be useful but too often they just spew so many false positives that real issues get missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SSRF](https://www.hackerone.com/blog-How-To-Server-Side-Request-Forgery-SSRF) is exploited by an attacker controlling an outgoing request that the server is making.  If `uri` is indeed hard-coded, then the attacker has no ability to influence where the request is going, so it would indeed look to be a false positive.  However, although Fortify is known for false positives, I have not seen it make that type of mistake (i.e. claimed SSRF despite a hard-coded URI), so I am a bit surprised to hear it.  Have you checked the whole source-to-sink trace that Fortify provides?  If it is reporting only that one line as the source and sink, then yes it is a false positive.  If there is more, then it would be helpful if you provided the full trace.

Answer (score 2):

As TheGreatContini said, uri should not be hard-coded. And also we can use UriComponents to build the URI before do the call.

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
  .scheme("http").host("www.yourdomain.com").path("/yourPath").build();
```

This will the build the URL for you and fix the Server-Side Request Forgery.

Comment: UriComponentsBuilder verifies the scheme, host, query params, and a few other things with some regex while constructing the URI. Which resolves the fortify server-side forgery request issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I get this Server-side request forgery alert in GitHub Code scanning.

Previous code I used restTemplate like this:

```
String uri = "https://my_url/{parm1}/product/{parm2}";
String finalUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
                .queryParam("name", "example")
                .buildAndExpand("paramValue1", "paramValue2")
                .toUriString();
restTemplate.exchange(finalUri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

However always get Server-side request forgery from GitHub Code scanning.

Then I resolved like this:

```
String uri = "https://my_url/{parm1}/product/{parm2}?name={name}";
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity,  String.class, "paramValue1", "paramValue2", "example");
```

Then actual request URL will be:

```
https://my_url/paramValue1/product/paramValue2?name=example
```

Answer (score 0):

this is FalsePositive from your SAST Scanner