# getting error in rest api while logging the response

Tags: java, security, fortify, rest

I have the below java code in which i making use of an rest template to exchange some data and getting response from third party service as shown below

```
 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(restApiUrl,
                HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        LOGGER.info("XML Response from UIDAI :" + response.getBody()); //** Error**//
```

but upon scanning with fortify it is showing he method restTemplateCall() in java class writes unvalidated user input to the log . An attacker could take advantage of this behavior to forge log entries or inject malicious content into the log

Please advise how to overcome from this .

Comment: Looks like this one has come up before. Consensus that time was false positive from fortify: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775798/how-to-fix-server-side-request-forgery-issue-in-spring-resttemplate